# comments longer than one line

Tags: c, filesystems, comments

So I was wondering if this is right; I have to count the comments longer than one line in a file:

```
    void commentsLongerThanOneLine(FILE* inputStream, FILE* outputStream) {
char c;
int i = 0;
while ((c = fgetc(inputStream) != EOF)) {
    if (c == '/' && '*' && '\n') i++;
}
printf("Number of comments longer than one line is : %d\n", i);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: First you need to learn about conditions and how they work. And learn the difference between assignment `=` and comparison for equality `==`.

Comment: What the heck is `c='/' && '*'`? That makes no sense at all. You're trying to compare `c` to multiple values, but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: It's more complicated than you think. Comment indicators might be within a literal string, and the `//` style might be commented out by the more important `/* comment */`

Comment: && means boolean AND the test for equality is == not =, Even if the line worked the way you think, it would always be false as you seem to test c against slash AND asterix AND new line which is impossible. You need to check against slash set a flag and check if the next character is asterix Then verify that there is a new line before the end of the comment (\*/) Also see the comment below about how // can span multiple lines and check that the /\* is not inside a //

Comment: Don't forget that a `//comment` can span more than one line if it contains the line continuation symbol `\\` (although MSVC gives a warning about such a comment).

Answer (score 0):

&& means boolean AND the test for equality is == not =,

You would need to have each indicator tested individually.

```
if ((c == '/') && (c == '*') && (c == '\n'))
```

**Of course this would always generate FALSE as it is an impossible statement.**

Even if the line worked the way you think, it would always be false as you seem to test c against slash AND asterix AND new line which is impossible. You need to check against slash set a flag and check if the next character is asterix Then verify that there is a new line before the end of the comment (*/)

// can span multiple lines and you need to check that the /* is not inside a // and vice versa.